# Payment solution for android app

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I'm developing an android app (iOS in the future) which will have some features locked till user pays a fee. It's going to be world wide application and my bank account is in Europe.

Currently I'm thinking of the combination Paypal+Payment gateway (debit cards, bank account transfers)+SMS payments.

The payment should be instant if possible.

What providers or what improvements to my solution idea would you recommend?

Comment: If you upload it to the google play store you have to implement a so called In-App-Purchasing/Billing via the Google Play Store services, otherwise your app could be deleted.

Comment: Oh, wasn't aware of this restriction. That means no Paypal, no SMS from the app etc. :-( At least it'll be easy to develop :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Google Play In-app Billing, check this url
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html